# What are the ways to present an unfinished software / WWW to a client while making it obvious it is work in progress?

Tags: website-design, software-recommendation, client-relations

Sometimes I would like to present some work and indicate clearly - this is **work in progress** - waiting for the final designs - but you can already test the functionality.

1st thoughts - **pink comic sans** - there is no way anyone could think this is a finished product.

Ideally something that would make the WWW look like https://balsamiq.com/ (a wireframing tool)
[image]

Maybe there is a CSS library for that?

---

**Another twist on the same question:**

Not working with the clients but software testing team. Telling them not to focus on the design but testing a functionality.

I really want to find a tool / library / feature that would 1-click enable "work in progress" look and feel.

Comment: No,  many nontechnical clients do not usually understand this. It does not make any difference what it looks like, which is why still to this day postit notes on a wall is a very good option. That they understand. This is mostly because some people outside fields that do design iterations on computers cant understand why something would be not finished when its on the computer. They think the plan goes idea->design->translation to computer. You have to explicitly explain it to people.

Comment: That leads to an idea - visual post in note with giant red all caps bold **TODO**

Answer (score 2):

One thing I know for certain.. the *moment* I show a client something I think is "below par" and merely a "placeholder" *that* is the element they will *love* and want to replicate as much as possible.

Even the Balsamiq wireframes can be misleading and some clients will like that style. Just as *some* clients may even like "pink comic sans". Just because something is *clearly* a "work in progress" to a designer that doesn't mean non-visual clients will perceive things that way. @joojaa's comment under the question is absolutely true.

So for me, with web structures and functionality tests.... **flat, text only, no styling or CSS whatsoever beyond setting font properties and element positioning**. I strip as much visual information away as possible. And even then it's possible to run into the "I love how clean it looks" comments from clients.